# Handling touch in React Native with time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am working on an onPress event in React Native. I have added two different actions `onPress`, `onLongPress`. I have two different functions associated with each of them. Now i have also added `delayLongPress={250}` and it's working with onLongPress. But when i try to call the onLongPress, it calls the onPress too. I don't want that to happen. I want to call the onpress when it's pressed just once and onLongPress when it's pressed for 250ms at least. How can i seperate those function calls.

Here's what i have right now:

```js
const onLongPress = () =>{
    console.log('Pressed long')
}
const onChange = () =>{
    console.log('Pressed')
}

return(
<Container
     onPress={onChange}
     onLongPress={onLongPress}
     delayLongPress={250}
>
</Container>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap it with the `TouchableHighlight`.

```
export default function App() {
  const onLongPress = () => {
    console.log('Pressed long');
  };
  const onChange = () => {
    console.log('Pressed');
  };
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight
      onPress={onChange}
      onLongPress={onLongPress}
      delayLongPress={250}
    >
      <Text>Press</Text> // Your child components goes here
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}
```

See the snack [here](https://snack.expo.dev/3ufOA3HS_)